# How do I replicate a single schema in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, replication

How do I replicate a single schema in postgresql?

I want to replicate only one schema when there are multiple schemas in the database.

Too many tables to use as "for table" for postgresql logical replication..

Comment: "Too many tables to use as "for table" for postgresql logical replication"  How many is that?

Comment: @jjanes about 2000..!

Comment: You could write some dynamic SQL in PL/pgSQL that iterates through all tables of a schema and registers them for logical replication.

Comment: [pglogical](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical) seems to make this easy using replication sets (I have never used that extension though)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh, thx.. !! but can't just include a single schema table for create publication?

Comment: i check the pglogical. thank you !

Comment: 2000 should not be a problem.  If that is too much typing, then script it!  If there were a way to include by schema, I think it would just be scripting it internally anyway.